# UPDATE FROM in Azure SQL DW?

Tags: sql-update, azure-synapse

I'm receiving an error in Azure SQL DW trying to do an UPDATE FROM query. The error is "FROM clause in UPDATE and DELETE statements cannot contain subquery sources or joins"

Is this just specific to SQL DW? I don't see anything wrong with this query otherwise. If it is a limitation of SQL DW, what's the alternative?

```
-- Permanent fact table with 5 billion rows
CREATE TABLE FactTable (Id1 INT, Id2 INT, EmailAddress NVARCHAR(100), Value1 INT)
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = HASH(EmailAddress));

-- Staging fact table with 10 million rows    
CREATE TABLE StageTable (Id1 INT, Id2 INT, EmailAddress NVARCHAR(100), Value1 INT)
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = HASH(EmailAddress), HEAP);

-- Add a secondary index that should help with joining to StageTable
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON FactTable (Id1, Id2);

UPDATE fact
SET
   Value1 = CASE WHEN stage.Value1 > fact.Value1 THEN stage.Value1 ELSE fact.Value1 END
FROM FactTable AS fact
INNER JOIN StageTable AS stage ON fact.Id1 = stage.Id1 AND fact.Id2 = stage.Id2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql) Azure SQL Data Warehouse does support `UPDATE` but does not support ANSI joins in the `FROM` clause.  You can use CTAS to work around.  Simple two-table update:

```
UPDATE dbo.FactTable
SET
   Value1 = CASE WHEN stage.Value1 > dbo.FactTable.Value1 THEN stage.Value1 ELSE dbo.FactTable.Value1 END
FROM dbo.StageTable AS stage
WHERE dbo.FactTable.Id1 = stage.Id1 
  AND dbo.FactTable.Id2 = stage.Id2;
```

More complex example with CTAS, copied wholesale from the [main UPDATE documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql#examples-includesssdwincludessssdw-mdmd-and-includesspdwincludessspdw-mdmd):

```
-- Create an interim table
CREATE TABLE CTAS_acs
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN)
AS
SELECT  ISNULL(CAST([EnglishProductCategoryName] AS NVARCHAR(50)),0)    AS [EnglishProductCategoryName]
,       ISNULL(CAST([CalendarYear] AS SMALLINT),0)                      AS [CalendarYear]
,       ISNULL(CAST(SUM([SalesAmount]) AS MONEY),0)                     AS [TotalSalesAmount]
FROM    [dbo].[FactInternetSales]       AS s
JOIN    [dbo].[DimDate]                 AS d    ON s.[OrderDateKey]             = d.[DateKey]
JOIN    [dbo].[DimProduct]              AS p    ON s.[ProductKey]               = p.[ProductKey]
JOIN    [dbo].[DimProductSubCategory]   AS u    ON p.[ProductSubcategoryKey]    = u.[ProductSubcategoryKey]
JOIN    [dbo].[DimProductCategory]      AS c    ON u.[ProductCategoryKey]       = c.[ProductCategoryKey]
WHERE   [CalendarYear] = 2004
GROUP BY
        [EnglishProductCategoryName]
,       [CalendarYear]
;

-- Use an implicit join to perform the update
UPDATE  AnnualCategorySales
SET     AnnualCategorySales.TotalSalesAmount = CTAS_ACS.TotalSalesAmount
FROM    CTAS_acs
WHERE   CTAS_acs.[EnglishProductCategoryName] = AnnualCategorySales.[EnglishProductCategoryName]
AND     CTAS_acs.[CalendarYear]               = AnnualCategorySales.[CalendarYear]
;

--Drop the interim table
DROP TABLE CTAS_acs
;
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but is slower than I'd like. I wonder if I can get the system to use another index or to minimize data movement between distributions.

Comment: Are you able to post some more realistic DDL eg with the distributions, data volumes and sample data?  Plan analysis for Azure SQL Data Warehouse is now much easier from the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) - see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/unlock-query-performance-with-sql-data-warehouse-using-graphical-execution-plans/).

Comment: Plus the usual Azure DW stuff about statistics, what DWU are you running at etc.  Please review this excellent article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-best-practices

Comment: I've added more details to the example, including a secondary index that I thought would help with the exclusion comparison. SSMS says that the plan ignores it though.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a good practice with ASDW (and APS/PDW) to avoid bulk updates like the plague.

Here's a pure CTAS alternative that will be faster in cases where you're updating a significant percentage of rows.

It assumes that id1 is a relatively good distribution key, and that the number of staging rows is less than the fact rows, making a replication feasible. This strategy should eliminate data movement between nodes.

If you had a very large staging table, creating a surrogate column in each table that was a combination of id1 and id2, then distributing both tables by the hash of that column, would give even better performance.

```
create  table FactTable (
        id1 int,
        id2 int,
        value1 int)
with    (distribution = hash(id1));

create  table StageTable (
        id1 int,
        id2 int,
        value1 int)
with    (distribution = replicate);

create  table UpdatedFact 
with    (distribution = hash(id1)) 
as
select  f.id1,
        f.id2,
        case when s.id1 is not null and s.value1 > f.value1 
            then s.value1
            else f.value1
            end as value1
from    FactTable f
        left outer join StageTable s
        on s.id1 = f.id1
        and s.id2 = f.id2

truncate table FactTable;
alter table UpdatedFact switch to FactTable;
drop table UpdatedFact;
```

Comment: Nice example Ron

Comment: I'll try this approach, but I'm skeptical that CTAS will be more efficient than simply updating the rows. My fact table has about 5 billion rows and each update will add about 4 million and update about 1 million.

Comment: Keep in mind that the CTAS can create new rows in the same pass, by using a FULL OUTER JOIN, which would eliminate the separate INSERT. With a full outer join you update the values from the RHS when the LHS is null. 5 billion:5million is an interesting ratio, I think your scepticism is healthy :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying what you attempted would work.  Just take away the joins and update one table from the other.

```
update FactTable
set this = that
from StageTable s where s.something = FactTable.something
```

Whether or not this is the best approach depends on your circumstances, but it will execute without throwing an error.